# What is FakeHttpContext?

Tags: cookies, httpcontext

I searched in many places but I couldn't find a complete explanation, what exactly does FakeHttpContext do, why should we use it, what is its relationship with HttpContext, thanks.

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);

    return context.Object;
}
```

Comment: Its exactly what it says - a fake context. It behaves like a real one - but without actually making http requests, so what it does and what it returns is only what you tell it to for the purposes of your tests. And, of course, used for unit testing as a general rule.

Comment: So it is used for the software developer to test?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.